# How to extract tags present above a closing tag in an XML document?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have an XML document with the following format:

```
<root>
    <W> word </W>
    <W> word2 </W>
    <Some random tag>
        <W> word 3 </W>
    </Some random tag>
    .
    .
    .
    <X>
        <W> </W>
        <W> </W>
    </X>
    <W> word4 </W>
    <W> word5 </W>
    <Some random tag>
        <W> word6 </W>
    </Some random tag>
    .
    .
    .
    <X>
        <W> </W>
        <W> </W>
    </X>
</root>
```

There are a bunch of tags above the `</X>`. There can be any order amongst them that is `<W>` may be present inside some other tag or even outside. I  wish to extract all the text in the `<W>` tag present before the `</X>` and put it in a list. Then the text in the`<W>` present between the first `</X>` and the second `</X>` should be put it in a new list.

How do I do so?

What I tried: I used the `xml` module. Since there is no particular order where `<W>` may be present, I iterate over all the tags. However, in this manner, I can't tell when the `</X>` closes which is a problem as there might be some `<W>` inside the `<X>` tag as well. Other than this method, I am out of ideas.

EDIT: To make things clear:

```
<root>
    <W> word </W>
    <W> word2 </W>
    <Some_random_tag>
        <W> word 3 </W>
    </Some_random_tag>
    <X>
        <W>alice </W>
        <W>bob </W>
    </X>
    <W> word4 </W>
    <W> word5 </W>
    <Some_random_tag>
        <W> word6 </W>
    </Some_random_tag>
    <X>
        <W>one </W>
        <W>two </W>
    </X>
</root>
```

In the above example, I need `word, word2, word3, Alice, Bob` in one list (All text in `<W>` present above the first `</X>`). And `word4, word5, word6, one, two` in another list.(All text in `<W>` present between the first `</X>` and the second `</X>`).